# NUMTODSINTERVAL in Redshift. Convert a number to hours

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, amazon-redshift, timezone-offset

My goal is to offset timestamps in table **Date_times** to reflect local timezones. I have a **Timezone_lookup** table that I use for that, which has a column *utc_convert* and its values are (2, -1, 5, etc.) depending on the timezone.

I used to use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` in Oracle to be able to convert the *utc_convert* values to hours so I can add/subtract from the datetimes in the **Date_times** table.

For Redshift I found `INTERVAL`, but that's only hardcoding the offset with a specific number.

I also tried:

```
SELECT CAST(utc as TIME) 
 FROM(
  SELECT *
  ,to_char(cast(utc_convert as int)||':00:00', 'HH24') as utc
from Timezon_lookup
)
```

But this doesn't work as some number in the *utc_convert* column have negative values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried multiplying the offset by an interval:

```
select current_timestamp + utc_convert * interval '1 hour'
```

Comment: This is genius!! It works perfectly and it's a simple code. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use the time zone of the user's session (which means you do not need to maintain a table of time zone look-ups or compensate for daylight savings time).

```
SELECT FROM_TZ( your_timestamp_column, 'UTC' ) AT LOCAL
FROM   Date_times
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e58b7/6)

In RedShift you should be able to use the [`CONVERT_TIMEZONE( ['source_timezone',] 'target_timezone', 'timestamp')`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/CONVERT_TIMEZONE.html) function rather adding a number of intervals. This would allow you to specify the `target_timezone` as a numeric offset from UTC or as a time zone name (which would automatically compensate for DST).

Comment: this is NOT valid redshift syntax.

Comment: @JonScott It is valid Oracle SQL and the question is tagged Oracle and the OP mentions using Oracle queries.

Comment: ok true - but the Op wants to convert the oracle to redshift i think :) "I used to use NUMTODSINTERVAL in Oracle" is the givaway.

Comment: @JonScott I've edited to make it clearer it is an Oracle answer - but hopefully there are similar functions in RedShift as trying to implement your own functionality to convert time zones is a recipe for making a huge mess (especially with daylight savings time).

Comment: Thanks very much, guys. Yeah, I'm sorry if I caused any confusions. I meant converting from Oracle to redshift. @JonScott 's answer solves the problem